# jump obstacle assembly code

Tags: assembly, nasm, ida

i have to understand what this code do for jump the exit call. i have only a static view and not a dynamic one because i can't use a debugger.
This is the code:

```
; int __cdecl main(int, char **, char **)
main proc near

var_14= dword ptr -14h
var_10= dword ptr -10h
handle= dword ptr -0Ch
fd= dword ptr -8
var_4= dword ptr -4
arg_4= dword ptr  0Ch

push    ebp
mov     ebp, esp
sub     esp, 24h
cmp     al, al
jz      short near ptr loc_8048DEC+3

xor     esp, esp

loc_8048DEC:
mov     dword ptr [ecx+42h], 2087D83h
jz      short loc_8048E25

mov     dword ptr [esp], 0Bh ; status
call    _exit
```

Answer (score 2):

The disassembly is obfuscated by the use of **overlapping opcodes.**

First of all, the instruction `cmp al, al` is guaranteed to set the zero flag, regardless of the contents of `al`.  So the `jz` conditional jump on the following line will be taken.

The `jz` jumps three bytes into the `mov dword ptr [ecx+42h], 2087D83h` instruction.  The hex representation for this instruction is `c7 41 42 83 7d 08 02`<sup>1</sup>.  So we actually begin executing at the `83`.

But `83 7d 08 02` disassembles to `cmp dword ptr [ebp+8], 2`.  Note that because this ends on the same instruction boundary as the misleading `mov` instruction that IDA displays, the next instructions to be executed line up with the disassembly given to you by IDA.

So then, in the next line, `jz short loc_8048E25`, we will only jump to `loc_8048E25` if the zero flag is set; that is, if `[ebp+8]` (which is our first parameter to `main`, i.e., `argc`) equals `2`.  Otherwise, we fall through and execute the next two instructions, which equate to `exit(11)`.

## To fix the disassembly in IDA...

You can unassemble the `mov` instruction by clicking on the `mov` line and pressing the `u` key.  You can similarly begin reassembling at `loc_8048DEC+3` with the `c` key.  You should save your database before doing this.

<sub>1. Many mnemonics can be represented by more than one sequence of bytes.  For example, this particular instruction could also potentially be represented as `c7 81 42 00 00 00 83 7d 08 02` but A) compilers tend to generate the shortest form of an instruction, and B) the resulting overlapped instructions wouldn't "make sense" and would likely segfault.  IDA can show you the actual byte representation of each instruction either in the Hex View or if you set `Opcodes > General > Number of opcode bytes` appropriately.</sub>